# Trying to create CAS template

Tags: c++, templates, compare-and-swap

at the moment I'm busy fiddling with CAS operations and lock/wait-free algorithms, and for my own sanity I decided to implement a template to handling all the casting for me:

VC6:

```
template <typename T> static inline T CAS(volatile T* pDest, T pCompare, T pValue)
{
    //static_assert(sizeof(T) != sizeof(PVOID),"CAS requires PVOID sized operands");
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(InterlockedCompareExchange(reinterpret_cast<PVOID*>(pDest),reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(pValue),reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(pCompare)));
}
```

GCC 4.4.1:

```
template <typename T> static inline T CAS(volatile T* pDest, T pCompare, T pValue)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) != sizeof(long),"CAS32 requires long sized operands");
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(InterlockedCompareExchangePointer(reinterpret_cast<volatile long*>(pDest),reinterpret_cast<long>(pValue),reinterpret_cast<long>(pCompare)));
}
```

However, using some simple test code, I cannot get this to work on a `volatile` destination, which is required to prevent reordering.

Test Code:

```
volatile int* p;
int i = 2;
int* pi = &i;
CAS(&p,NULL,pi);
```

Under VC6 I get this error:

```
error C2782: 'T __cdecl CAS(volatile T *,T,T)' : template parameter 'T' is ambiguous
        could be 'int'
        or       'volatile int *'
```

and GCC spits out this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'CAS(volatile int**, NULL, int*&)'
```

is it possible to get a template for CAS ops that doesn't break when the destination is `volatile` or am I stuck with a macro?

Comment: `static_assert`? Are you using C++0x?

Comment: @KennyTM: for the GCC build, yes, under VC I have a macro to map to to an invalid array index. its not tagged C++0x as i'm trying to avoid C++0x constructs except those emulatable with macros.

Comment: `InterlockedCompareExchange` or `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` . you should not mix them.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ: VC6 has no `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer`, hence why its def of `InterlockedCompareExchange` is that of `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer`. however, that does bring up a (semi)bug in my GCC code, should be casting to `PVOID`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK if i call the CAS function as follows:

```
CAS<int*>( &p, NULL, pi );
```

Then I get a different error:

```
error C2664: 'CAS' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'volatile int **' to 'int *volatile *'
```

This gives more of a clue as to what is going wrong.

One way to solve it would be to introduce a typedef as follows:

```
    typedef int* pint_t;

volatile pint_t p;
int i = 2;
pint_t pi = &i;
CAS<pint_t>( &p, NULL, pi );
```

Comment: technically, `NULL` should be `(void*)0`, but casting `NULL` to `int*` makes no difference, GCC still spits out: `error: no matching function for call to 'CAS(volatile int**, int*, int*&)'`

Comment: @Necrolis:  Re-wrote my answer :)

Comment: another way to define that pointer correctly is `int* volatile p;`

Comment: did some testing, and this works fine, only `p` needs to be of type `pint_t`, this is a pain in the butt however, as it makes more work than it solves, seems I'll just go with the macro after all :|